# Inserting special HTML characters into XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, escaping

I produce an XML string with this expression in JavaScript:

```
var xml = '<xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">' + dom.outerHTML + '</xml>'
```

(`dom` is some node in the document tree.)

Later I read this back with:

```
... = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
```

Usually it works fine, but fails when one of the fields in `dom` contains a non-breaking space character, typed manually with Alt+0160.
In `dom.outerHTML` it appears as `&nbsp;`, but the `parseFromString` function returns this:

```
<xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black">
        <h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3>
        <div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 139: Entity 'nbsp' not defined↵</div>
        <h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3>
    </parsererror>
    ...
</xml>
```

(It is actually the function result, not an exception! Very strange solution (: .)

I've tried `&amp;nbsp;` too, this succeded without `<parsererror>` tag, but was read back as the `"&nbsp;"` string, not the UNICODE 160 code point.

Probably other HTML spec chars are affected too.

Where and how should I escape/replace the special HTML characters to get back exactly the same `dom` as the original?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `<![CDATA[]]>`  to perform Character data. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Comment: Can't you use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) instead?

Answer (score 1):

As @forty-two suggested, `XMLSerializer` solved the problem:

```
var xml = '<xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">' 
  + (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(dom) 
  + '</xml>'
```

This inserts the non-breaking space character directly into the result. (No '&' characters.)
The read side needs no change.
Thanks.